# How do I add Dataflow memory usage to Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-stackdriver

**Problem:**

We want to understand the memory usage of our Cloud Dataflow job, preferably per worker/VM. We'd like to add this to Stackdriver, but it seems we can only add cpu usage and disk I/O metrics.

**Question:**

Is there a way to add Cloud Dataflow memory usage to Stackdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-stackdriver-monitoring#receive_worker_vm_metrics_from_monitoring_agent) you can use the `--experiments=enable_stackdriver_agent_metrics` flag to enable Agent metrics for your Dataflow job. This will include [JVM metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-jvm) such as `memory/usage`.